# Clear all browser history in backend using c#

Tags: c#, browser-cache, pageload

How do I clear all my browsers' history (IE,Chrome,Mozilla) using C# in the backend without the user being notified?
I have included the following code in the Page Load Method :

```
     Response.AppendHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
     Response.AppendHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
     Response.AppendHeader("Expires", "0"); // Proxies.
```

and the following is the code that I have included above the header content  :

```
      <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />

      <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />

      <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />​
```

Despite all of this the browser history is not being deleted .Can something else be done to achieve the same?

Comment: The browser history has nothing to do with the backend. It is local and is part of the browser implementation. You cannot delete it from on the backend or, in fact, without the user's consent.

Comment: I would be really concerned if backend could clear my browser history... I like my browser history.

Comment: Thank You Marcell .Actually I have a JavaScript Gantt chart which only seems to display the data when the browser history is cleared. It stops working and its functionalities stop if not so! It works well once the history is cleared only for a short tme though.

Comment: I think you've gotta figure out why the data can only displayed when the browser history is cleared instead of clearing the browser's history..